# How to match multiple sibling routes with React Router V6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement tabs navigation using React router v6. To do so, I need the following rendering pattern:

- Render `<Tabs />` and `<TabPanelA />` when URL is `/tabsDemo/a`
- Render `<Tabs />` and `<TabPanelB />` when URL is `/tabsDemo/b`

`<Tabs />` is a navigation bar that allows users to navigate between tab panels A and B. It needs to be aware of `currentTab` so that it can change the corresponding tab's color. It also needs to be constantly rendered even as the user navigates across different tab panels.


However, my current code only renders `<TabPanelA />` when the URL is `/tabsDemo/a` because `/tabsDemo/a` is more specific than `/tabsDemo/:currentTab`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="tabsDemo" element={<Outlet />}>
        <Route path=":currentTab" element={<Tabs />} />
        <Route path="a" element={<TabPanelA />} />
        <Route path="b" element={<TabPanelB />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

How can I achieve the aforementioned rendering pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most trivial method would be to render the `Tabs` component in each place you want.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="tabsDemo" element={<Outlet />}>
        <Route path=":currentTab" element={<Tabs />} />
        <Route
          path="a"
          element={(
            <>
              <Tabs />
              <TabPanelA />
            </>
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="b"
          element={(
            <>
              <Tabs />
              <TabPanelB />
            </>
          )}
        />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

It sounds like you want to render the `Tabs` component regardless. For this you should convert it into a layout route that renders the `Outlet`.

Example:

```
const Tabs = () => {
  ... tabs logic ...

  return (
    ...
    <Outlet />
    ...
  );
};
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="tabsDemo" element={<Tabs />}>
        <Route path="a" element={<TabPanelA />} />
        <Route path="b" element={<TabPanelB />} />
        <Route
          path=":currentTab"
          element={/* some component to read the `currentTab` param ??? */}
        />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your second example is almost exactly how I have since decided to implement the feature. To future readers: I used `useLocation` in place of `...tabs logic...` within `<Tabs />` so that it can be aware of the current displayed tab panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<Route path="/tabsDemo" element={<Tabs />}>
   <Route path="/a" element={<TabPanelA />} />
   <Route path="/b" element={<TabPanelB />} />
</Route>
```

#### See more:

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route#routes-and-route

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. v6 doesn't support `exact` anyway.

Comment: @jalen_blue try now.

Comment: Received ```Uncaught Error: Absolute route path "/a" nested under path "/tabsDemo" is not valid. An absolute child route path must start with the combined path of all its parent routes.```